# Sending Array from Form into body object in Promise React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, object, request

I have an array that I am sending into a a request body, where it is structure as an object, but in this object is the array. How can I send in this array and access the values in this array so I am able to reference it directly in an attribute in the request body? I am working in React.

**react-component.js**

```
  const requestPromise = () =>
    new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
      try {
        const body = {
          crf2e_first_name: form.firstName,
          crf2e_last_name: form.lastName,
          crf2e_role_id: form.roles.roleId // 'This is an attribute I need from the array',
          crf2e_role_name: form.roles.name // 'This is an attribute I need from the array',

        }
}

  const handleAddRole = () => {
    if (form.roles[0].name === 'Role1') {
      setForm({
        ...form,
        roles: [...form.roles, { roleId: '1', name: 'Role1' }]
      })
    }
```

Comment: Are you always trying to access the last element in the array?

Comment: There could be multiple objects in the roles array, but basically I need to pass the entire array in the Object @JacobStephenson

Comment: so `crf2e_role_id` would hold an array of all the roles ids for example?

Comment: Yes precisely @JacobStephenson

Answer (score 0):

You can [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) over the roles array to return seperate id, and name arrays for your request body

```
const body = {
    crf2e_first_name: form.firstName,
    crf2e_last_name: form.lastName,
    crf2e_role_id: form.roles.map(role => role.roleId) // returns ['1']
    crf2e_role_name: form.roles.map(role => role.name) // returns ['Role1'] 
}
```